# Laravel error in /bootstrap/start.php: \Illuminate\Foundation\Application not found

Tags: php, laravel

So, I installed Laravel on a dev server (php5.5.3, standard installation, mcrypt installed), and I get the following error message:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Application' not found in /[path_to_laravel_app]/bootstrap/start.php on line 14
```

Quite odd, and I haven't seen a solution to this file, although I've seen plenty of similar errors. Any advice welcome. Thanks!

Comment: Try running `php artisan optimize` in the command line?

Comment: Thanks -- tried it to no avail.

Comment: Any errors? Also, can you make sure that `~/bootstrap/start.php` exists?  Try removing your `vendor` directory and `composer.lock` file and re-running `composer install`.

Comment: Fixed it. Fantastic. Removing the vendor directory worked like a charm!

Comment: Posted as an answer so you can mark as selected for others.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`/bootstrap/start.php` is created after `composer install` by running Laravel's `php artisan optimize`.  I've had a lot of issues on this during upgrades of Laravel, but removing `/bootstrap/start.php`, `composer.lock`, and the `vendor` directory and re-running `composer install` should fix this issue.

Comment: any work around for doing it in a server that I don't have shell access to?

Comment: @kevin not quite sure, but it seems that Laravel ***requires*** using Composer to install dependencies.  If you have a way to use Composer without shell access, you can still use this answer.  Delete `boostrap/start.php`, `composer.lock`, and the `vendor` directory.  Then re-install Composer.

Comment: In case anyone arrives here, this has changed since 2010. bootstrap/start.php is no longer generated.

Comment: I am facing same issue in laravel file after updating composer.json after including the intervention/image

Answer (score 8):

Run this command:

```
composer update --no-scripts
```

In my case I have added another required package(Guzzle) in the compser.json file separately(in the last line but it should be after the laravel package line) and updated the compsoser and came across this issue.

I have checked and my vendor/laravel folder has gone. That was preventing me to run any artisian command.

So "--no-scripts" worked for me as it prevents any scripts to be included before executing artisan.

You can use another method in case you are having issues.

1. Install another raw laravel and copy all the files from the vendor
   file to your old repostory.
2. Change permission of storage and bootstrap folder to 775 or 777.
3. Delete everything in the session and view folder of storage/framework

Comment: it did not worked for me :( , I also tried deleting the vendor and composer.lock and executing composer install still it did not work same error I am getting whenever I run any artisan command

Comment: Sorry you are having issue. Try this. #1 install another raw laravel and copy all the files from the vendor file to your old repostory. #2 Change permission of storage and bootstrap folder to 775 or 777. #3 Delete everything in the session and view folder of storage/framework.

Comment: Nice to know that @Notflip

Answer (score 2):

Correct the composer.json. This might happen after you have added a new package configuration by dublicating the require tag.

Do not create yet another

```
require: {
     ..
    }
```

use the previous defined one.

Then follow the accepted answer to re-install the packages.

Answer (score 1):

Just Run the command

```
composer install --no-scripts
```

Or,

```
composer update --no-scripts
```

Answer (score 0):

Double check your composer.json file. If you have error on "require": section this error will occur.

**Just restore a previous version of composer.json file and run composer update.**