# Laravel app upload on web hosting: Fatal error: Class 'Patchwork\Utf8\Bootup' not found

Tags: laravel, localhost, web-hosting, fatal-error

My app works fine on localhost, but when I upload on web hosting I have this error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Patchwork\Utf8\Bootup' not found in /web/htdocs/www.liguria-eventi.it/home/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 46
```

My hosting service is Shared hosting on server Linux with Apache and PHP 5.4.

In local I have Windows 8 with XAMPP.

Thanks

Comment: Did you upload the `vendor` directory as well?

Comment: What do you mean with "as well"? I uploaded the whole folder as it was in the local.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have 2 require in your composer.json.

I've got the same error, and this was my problem.

I was having something like :

```
"require": {
                "laravel/framework": "4.2.*"
        },
"require": {
             "patchwork/utf8": "1.1.*"
        },
```

while i needed only 1 require {} :

```
 "require": {
                "laravel/framework": "4.2.*",
             "patchwork/utf8": "1.1.*",
            "queiroz/whmcs-api": "dev-master"
        },
```

**EDIT :**

i also needed to add

'Patchwork\Utf8\Utf8ServiceProvider'

in the 'providers' array under the file app/config/app.php

**EDIT :**

Please reffer to the comment below if you have a "Laravel error in /bootstrap/start.php: \Illuminate\Foundation\Application not found" error after you fixed :)

Comment: If you see a `Laravel error in /bootstrap/start.php: \Illuminate\Foundation\Application not found` error right after you fixed your conposer.json, take a look at this Question : [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21053231/laravel-error-in-bootstrap-start-php-illuminate-foundation-application-not-fo]